# How to get price from the [product_option] returned by salesOrderInfo method of SOAP API

Tags: php, magento, soap

When I run following code in magento root

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/mymagento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
$session = $client->login('testuser', 'testuser');

$result = $client->salesOrderInfo($session,'100000097');            
echo"<pre>";
    print_r($result);
echo"</pre>";
```

I get  [product_options] like following way in output

```
[product_options] => a:2:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:10:{s:4:"uenc";s:100:"aHR0cDovL2RlbW8uc2lnbWFpbmZvLmluOjgzL3JmZy9pbmRleC5waHAvbGFuZXNzZS1vY2Nhc2lvbmFsLXRhYmxlLXNldC5odG1s";s:7:"product";s:3:"115";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:13:"bundle_option";a:3:{i:47;s:3:"129";i:48;s:3:"131";i:49;s:3:"133";}s:17:"bundle_option_qty";a:3:{i:47;s:1:"1";i:48;s:1:"1";i:49;s:1:"1";}s:22:"select_super_attribute";a:1:{i:48;a:1:{i:182;s:3:"164";}}s:5:"block";a:1:{i:0;s:7:"options";}s:5:"awacp";s:1:"1";s:8:"no_cache";s:1:"1";}s:27:"bundle_selection_attributes";s:122:"a:4:{s:5:"price";d:159;s:3:"qty";d:1;s:12:"option_label";s:31:"Save on these additional pieces";s:9:"option_id";s:2:"49";}";}
```

How can I get the product price from this?
I there any direct function to access the price, instead of using `unserialize` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call the native PHP `unserialize` function as `unserialize($result['product_options'])` that should return you an array

Comment: I know this. But i was thinking if there is another way.

Comment: In fact, it should have another way because normally you shold receive the response as a PHP array and not as a serialized array as shown in the various samples I show at https://www.wsdltophp.com/Blog/Use-WsdlToPhp-to-manage-your-Magento-website-with-its-SOAP-API. Do you know why you get a serialized array?

Comment: If yow will run the same code on default magento you will get same what I am getting